# Unable to update R packages in default library on Windows 7

Tags: r, windows-7

I'm trying to update packages on RGui (64-bit) using `update.packages` but I'm getting the following message:

```
Warning in install.packages(update[instlib == l, "Package"], l, contriburl = contriburl,  :
  'lib = "C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-212~1.1/library"' is not writable
Error in install.packages(update[instlib == l, "Package"], l, contriburl = contriburl,  : 
  unable to install packages
```

I've looked at the library folder in Explorer and it has read only set, so I removed it. However, it reappears when I check the properties again immediately after doing this. Installing new packages is unaffected since they have a separate folder in my user profile.

Is there a trick to getting this to work?

Comment: see 2.24 and 4.2 in the R for Windows FAQ.

Comment: Thanks, this covers it exactly. I should RTFM more often!

Comment: For me, I had to manually extract the zip file into the tools folder.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Usually you need administrator rights to change things in program files. Try running RGui as administrator.

Comment: That will make it work but it's really not the right way to do things. The idea is that you don't run programs with administrator rights.

Comment: +1 ok, now I finally realise that the question is about updating the packages supplied with r. And yes this is the answer. But just elevate to admin when you need to update. In normal use run as standard user.

Comment: Thanks, I thought I was running in admin mode, but it seems the Win 7 model is quite different to my XP experience.

Comment: @James It's called UAC. Some quick web searches should be enough to bring you up to speed, if you aren't already!

Comment: @David Heffernan Thanks, that makes sense of what is happening.

Comment: This helped me with "Revolution R" - they rebuild R environment and it is used now in SQL Server 2016. What is important here: even if you have permissions and if you are indeed a complete sysadmin, you still need to find "RGui.exe" (C:\Program Files\RRO\RRO-3.2.2-for-RRE-7.5.0\R-3.2.2\bin\x64) and click "Run as administrator"

Comment: Sacha Epskamp. Thank you very much, 12 (twelve) years after posting and your reply helped me.

Answer (score 56):

It happens the same to me, and after coding hours and hours in "R" of Gui Project, i got bored because it is much easier to read a code when the interface uses colours for a certain type of words (commands). Well, i decided to install RStudio, but soon i was faced with package installation problems. It seems that happens in Windows 7. The way that I used to solve this problem with RSutido was:

1. C:\Program Files\R - and this is the folder that contains "R" and not RStudio folder!
2. Right click for properties.
3. Security.
4. In "Group or user names" select your name
5. click "Edit"
6. select "Full control"
7. Apply and click <kbd>OK</kbd>

After this steps you should be ok to install all the packages :-)

Comment: thanks for this! I just ran into this same problem and if you're already in the middle of trying to install the package, this approach actually works.

Comment: This solved my issues entirely! I am running off a university computer and needed to gain admin privileges in order to enable full control. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

try

```
install.packages('package_name', lib='folder')
```

you can specify a folder for installation of the libraries, for which you have writing permission.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 4):

Uninstalling from C:\Program Files and re-installing to C:\R worked for me

[See mdsumner's comment and Windows FAQ found [here](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/base/rw-FAQ.html#How-do-I-install-R-for-Windows_003f)]

"...Users of Vista/Windows 7/8/Server 2008/2012 installing for a single user using an account with administrator rights1 ***should consider installing into a non-system area (such as C:\R)***"

Comment: This works for me after wasting 6 hours trying all  kind of solution. I confirm I have all my rights on the folder btw.

Answer (score 2):

I had this exact problem and just changed it for myself.  That is I navigated to C:/PROGRAM/R and then right clicked on the R to bring up properties.  Went to the Security tab clicked on the Group/User that you want to add permissions for.  That for me was USER then clicked EDIT and then selected the boxes that were unchecked to Allow control over.  I had to do this specifically for each user (of course I was running the entire time as administrator).  Clicked Apply/OK and all is well.  I can now update/install/ new libraries and what have you for this computer without having to run R as the admin.

Answer (score 1):

Without more information, my first guess is that you have insufficient permissions to write to the R site library folder. Usually, R would prompt for creation of a user lib folder to install to, but this can be unreliable under Windows Vista/Windows 7.

Try:

```
dir.create(Sys.getenv("R_LIBS_USER"), recursive = TRUE)
```

In the R console. Libraries should now install to /Users/"you"/R/win-library/x.y, for which you have the appropriate permissions.

Comment: I already have a personal library that got created when I first installed new packages. The problem lies with updating the default library created on installation.

Answer (score 1):

I have BitDefender 2018 and had to disable "safe files" and "firewall".

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar error recently. Running RStudio as an administrator didn't work. And changing the permissions on `C:/Programs/R` is a bit clumsy, as you'd have to repeat it for every user.

The solution for me was changing the library path for R as follows

1. In the R console, type `.libPaths()`. You'll see something like this,

   `"Path/to/user/R/win-library/x.x" "C:/Programs/R/R-x.x.x"`

   The two paths exist because you have defined a user-specific lib path during installation. Replace x.x.x with your R version.
2. Now set the lib path to the Programs directory

   `.libPaths = "C:/Programs/R/R-x.x.x"`

Now you can `install.packages()` or `update.packages()`!

Answer (score 0):

Try choosing a cranmirror location closer to you with this command first

```
chooseCRANmirror()
```

And then try installing the package. This command worked for me when I was getting warnings on installing "devtools".

Answer (score 0):

I also had this kind of problem in Windows 10, Then I disable "Safe Files" in Bitdefender 2018. It works for me

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes there may also be a possibility that your Antivirus is blocking the application. Unblock the application if anti virus has blocked it.