# Cant install a package in R

Tags: r, installation, package

I cant seem to install this package.
package ‘zoo’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked

Warning: unable to move temporary installation ‘C:\Users\Xiang\Documents\R\win-library\3.2\file248444b815fb\zoo’ to ‘C:\Users\Xiang\Documents\R\win-library\3.2\zoo’

Does anyone have a solution to solve this problem?

Thank you.

Comment: You should tag the question with the language and package manager you are using. "install" and "package" are pretty meaningless on their own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of potential solutions at this link: [Windows 7, update.packages problem: "unable to move temporary installation"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5700505/windows-7-update-packages-problem-unable-to-move-temporary-installation)

Could be an antivirus problem, or possibly lacking administrator privileges. The link recommends installing R in a different folder, or downloading the zip file for the package and installing it by hand.

Comment: how do u download the zip file folder and installing it by hand?

Comment: You can download the zoo package at: http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/zoo/index.html, then if you're using Windows you can install it by clicking the "Packages" menu, then "Install packages from local zip files"

Answer (score 0):

user3395158's solution worked for me. I had a similar problem with rstudioapi. I'd recommend trying RStudio. It has a built in interface for downloading packages directly from CRAN to the directory of your choice.

If you're using RStudio you can go to the "Tools" menu, then "Install Packages...", then select repository under the "Install from:" drop-down. Type in your package name below "Packages", like I did in my screenshot. Then you specify the directory to install the package, under the "Install to Library" drop-down. Meaning you should have  ‘C:\Users\Xiang\Documents\R\win-library\3.2\’ in the box, instead of my directory.

Hope that helps some!
[image: Dialog box in RStudio]