# Understanding install.packages() behaviour re repos and dependencies

Tags: r, installation, dependencies, package

I (finally) just installed ggplot2 by doing it from R directly and turning off antivirus.  (It had previously failed out on moving the temp files for stringi and magrittr, so I followed [the advice in StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5700505/windows-7-update-packages-problem-unable-to-move-temporary-installation).)

And it worked.  But I have a few puzzles about its behaviour.  The command I used was:

```
install.packages("ggplot2", repos = getOption("repos"), dependencies = TRUE)
```

Two things that happened as a result puzzled me:

- it didn't ask me what repos I wanted to use - but just went to
  imperial (which is fine with me)
- it didn't install the dependencies - which I discovered when I did
  library, so I installed the missing ones manually one by one (luckily
  there were only two - the two that had failed out when I had tried an
  install from RStudio with my antivirus on)

I have read the documentation on install.packages() but haven't understood it, as both these behaviours were different from what I expected.    I thought I would get a query about what repos to go to,  and I thought I would get the dependencies tagging along on the install.

Can someone explain?

Thanks.

Comment: amazing for the dependencies. It should work fine. The only case I know that `install.package` ignore dependencies , is for `NULL repos`.

Comment: I wonder if (trying) to set the repos interactively might ignore the dependency flag?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It *always* install dependencies. That is the whole point of

1. having repos -- and why CRAN was so important over these 20 years, and
2. declaring dependencies in `DESCRIPTION`.

Now, I set my repos in the startup file (`Rprofile.site` in my case, see `help(Startup)` and its examples section for how). You can also just call `options()` before calling `install.packages()`.  The `dependencies=TRUE` is also superfluous.

But thinks you need to check and did not tell us: source or binary installation?  What OS?  What is your R version and does it mesh with what the repos expect -- a *current* version on R?

Comment: Binary.  Windows.  3.2.0, which isn't exactly up to date.   Do you think it failed because I'm not on 3.3.2?

Comment: Your answer clarifies the designed behaviour regarding dependencies,  thanks.  As to repositories,  I have not set a default, but maybe it could  be the case that having installed one package in my session already, having picked the repository from a pick list, that option would be set and stay set for the session (regardless of whatever indigestable stuff I was trying to tell it as parameters?)  If so, the behaviour re. repositories makes sense.