# ERROR: 'configure' exists but is not executable -- see the 'R Installation and Administration Manual'

Tags: r, linux, ubuntu, linux-mint, install.packages

Ubuntu, Linux Mint, Debian

```
ERROR: 'configure' exists but is not executable -- see the 'R Installation and Administration Manual'

Warning in install.packages : installation of package ‘e1071’ had non-zero exit status
```

If you run into the error-code above on Linux here is a simple fix for you:

**Why does this error occur?**

Because the folder R temporarily stores i.e. downloads package files into is 'marked' as non-executable i.e. noexec. This means that compilation, as is required for in this case for the given package is forbidden.

**How to fix it?**

I unmount the partition/folder, change the status to executable and subsequently mount it again. Here is the terminal code for Ubuntu & Linux Mint:

```
mount -o remount,exec /tmp
```

In case you want to revoke executable settings find the code below:

```
mount -o remount,noexec /tmp
```

---

**Can this happen on Windows?**

Yes it can, and I can confirm the same issue. The solution is somewhat better documented here:
[Unable to update R packages in default library on Windows 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5700505/windows-7-update-packages-problem-unable-to-move-temporary-installation)

1. C:\Program Files\R - this folder contains "R", not the RStudio folder!
2. Right click for properties.
3. Security.
4. In "Group our user names" select your name.
5. Click "Edit".
6. Select "Full Control".
7. Click "Apply" and "OK".

Comment: This post has saved me twice now :)