# problems with installing r packages on windows 10

Tags: r

I'm having problems installing r packages using R3.4.1 on windows 10.

E.g. I get the following message when trying to install a package:

```
package ‘ctv’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
Warning in install.packages :
  unable to move temporary installation ‘C:\Program Files\R\R-3.4.1\library\file34470c9f23\ctv’ to ‘C:\Program Files\R\R-3.4.1\library\ctv’
```

I would really appreciate any assistance to resolve this issue.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Windows 7, update.packages problem: "unable to move temporary installation"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5700505/windows-7-update-packages-problem-unable-to-move-temporary-installation)

Answer (score 3):

Normally one puts the library in C:\user\yourname\Documents\R\win-library.  Each version of R will have its library in a separate folder within that folder. In that case you won't get this error.  If you reinstall R and accept the default for the library location then it will put the library there and you won't get this error.

If you prefer the configuration you have now because, for example, there are multiple users on your PC that need to share the library, then you will need to be Administrator each time you install a package; however, note that your current configuration is less secure than the default.

Comment: Thank you but this only happens with Windows 10 even though I am logged in as an administrator. It did not happen with Windows 7.

Comment: @Robert have you tried solutions in the voted duplicate?