# Can I move all packages out of C:\Program Files\R\R-3.3.0\library\ into a user directory?

Tags: r, install.packages

My problem:

```
> update.packages()
Warning: package 'nlme' in library 'C:/Program Files/R/R-3.3.0/library' will not be updated
```

This is well-known and is because writing to C:\Program Files\ needs Administrator (or at least elevated privileges).

I dislike the suggestions offered here, [Unable to update R packages in default library on Windows 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5059692/unable-to-update-r-packages-in-default-library-on-windows-7), which are to either run R as an `Administrator`, or to give `User`-level permissions to write to `C:\Program Files\R\library`.

**Question:** I was wondering if I can simply move *all* the packages out of `C:\Program Files\R\R-3.3.0\library\` into my (user-writable) directory, `D:/My_Documents_VV/R/win-library/3.3`? I'm worried about moving core packages such as `boot` and `base`.

(I realize that even if I could do it, it might cause a problem later when I upgrade R : there would be a clash between the new `base` and the one in my directory which I copy over to `R/win-library/x.y/`. I'm happy to take that risk / upgrade headache in this case)

```
> .libPaths()
[1] "D:/My_Documents_VV/R/win-library/3.3"
[2] "C:/Program Files/R/R-3.3.0/library"

COLOURS [19442] ~/ > ls -1 '/c/Program Files/R/R-3.3.0/library/'
base
boot
class
cluster
codetools
compiler
datasets
foreign
graphics
grDevices
grid
KernSmooth
lattice
MASS
Matrix
methods
mgcv
nlme
nnet
parallel
rpart
spatial
splines
stats
stats4
survival
tcltk
tools
translations
utils
```

Comment: Some are strong advocates of this, [see e.g., `installr::create.global.library`](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/installr/docs/create.global.library). It can save you from needing to re-install every single package when you do a minor version bump in R.

Comment: I wouldn't literally copy the files. But as mentioned above you can install packages in any non-default library location you like.

Comment: Just copying the files will work in *most* cases, but then the cases that don't become unpleasant surprises down the road. You'll probably want to modify your `.Rprofile.site` file to add your global library to your library paths at start-up.

Comment: @Gregor, thanks for the suggestion. I do use the `Renviron.site` file in the `$INSTALL_DIR/etc/` to add to `.libPaths()`. It's not exactly a "global" library, but version-specific (so that I can still use the old version of R + packages in case I need to reproduce some results)