# Unable to install sandwich package: error in unzip

Tags: r, install.packages

In trying to install sandwish package I got the following:

> install.packages("sandwich") Installing package into
>   ‘C:/Users/Renato/Documents/R/win-library/3.4’ (as ‘lib’ is
>   unspecified) also installing the dependency ‘zoo’
>
> tentando a URL
>   'https://vps.fmvz.usp.br/CRAN/bin/windows/contrib/3.4/zoo_1.8-1.zip'
>   Content type 'application/zip' length 915666 bytes (894 KB) downloaded
>   894 KB
>
> tentando a URL
>   'https://vps.fmvz.usp.br/CRAN/bin/windows/contrib/3.4/sandwich_2.4-0.zip'
>   Content type 'application/zip' length 1243148 bytes (1.2 MB)
>   downloaded 1.2 MB
>
> Error in unzip(zipname, exdir = dest) :    não foi possível abrir o
>   arquivo
>   'C:/Users/Renato/Documents/R/win-library/3.4/file1f8450045342/zoo/doc/zoo-design.pdf':
>   Permission denied

Any help?

Comment: probably of help: https://stackoverflow.com/q/42807247/4137985

Comment: translation: "tentando" = trying; "não foi possivel abrir o arquivo" = it was not possible open the file.

Comment: sounds like you're having permissions issues

Comment: Thank you Cath for the clue. I've already allowed my antivirus (Avast) unblock the access (files and path)  but I'm still getting the same error message.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, I solved it by disabling antivirus software (not including Windows Security).