# Install hts package in R studio 1..463

Tags: r, time-series

I am trying to install a time series package in R studio (hts), however, I am getting an error:

"Error in install.packages : cannot open file 'C:/Users/Salam/Documents/R/win-library/3.5/file39b01ea77002/glue/DESCRIPTION': Permission denied"

I tried turning off the firewall, the user that I am using has a full control on the folder, I also removed the check from the option "read only", running R as an administrator.

anyone has an idea?

Thanks.

Comment: This post "[r - installing package - cannot open file - permission denied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42807247/r-installing-package-cannot-open-file-permission-denied)" may be helpful.

Comment: I did something similar, I changed the path of installing libraries using ".libPaths" instruction and then copied the installed libraries to the original R folder. It worked fine! thanks.